# extracting the last day of the quarter from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a daily time series and I want to pick out the data for the last day of the quarter. I tried doing this by generating a series for the last day of the quarter and merging it with the other dataframe, but to no avail.

My Python code is here:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tim Peterson\Documents\Tom\Rocky\DJIA.csv", index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

ds1 = pd.DataFrame(s1, columns=[ 'DJIA'])

date1 = "2014-10-10"  # input start date
date2 = "2016-01-07"  # input end date

month_list = [i.strftime("%b-%y") for i in pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='MS')]

ds2 =pd.date_range(date1, date2, freq='BQ')

eom = pd.DataFrame(ds2 )

mergedDf = ds1.merge(eom, left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(mergedDf)

when I run this I get

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [DJIA, 0]
Index: []

Comment: Please share your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
dates = pd.date_range(date1, date2, freq='BQ')

out = ds1[ds1.index.isin(dates)]
```